# Customer Login error in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have a site in open cart. there is a problem when user login and go to another pages account automatically logout. is their any code problem or session and how can i sort this problem. any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? Also, what is the OC version you are using?

Comment: yes i am using journal2 theme and latest version.

Comment: The quick test you could do is enable the default theme and see you have the login issue still. If not, the issue is coming from theme files. I have not used that theme before, does it come with it's own controllers? Check $this->customer->logout() is called unnecessarily or empty the session by mistake.

Comment: okay thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

you can also check OC default Error log file reside in Your Directory **\system\logs\error.txt,**
may  be this will help  you to find error.
Best Of Luck

and yes , first check 
Go to System -> Settings -> Edit -> Server and make sure Log Errors is set to Yes.